Запуск программы на python с сайта
Есть программа, написанная на языке python, и есть сайт, который я пишу (пишу с помощью Django к слову, так его изучаю пока что).
Необходимо по нажатию на кнопку запускать эту самую программу, чтобы она работала в фоновом режиме (программа - по сути бот для Дискорда, поэтому напрямую с работой сайта она не связана). Вот и появился вопрос, а как это сделать? Код в PyScript?

По идее можно через multiprocessing из того же приложения django запускать. pyscript - нет, он в браузере выполняется, на компе пользователя, а ваш бот должен на вашем сервере работать.

Всеже правильней его запускать через менеджмент команду или через брокера вроде целери

Если и сайт и скрипт находятся на одном сервере, то последний можно вызвать через командную строку с помощью subprocess:
import subprocess
...
command = 'python3 /ПУТЬ ДО СКРИПТА/script.py'
subprocess.Popen(command , shell=True)

Использование Popen() позволяет запустить другой скрипт и не ожидать его завершения.
Для более продвинутой работы с внешними процессами можно использовать Celery.

Это плохо работает при деплое

Я так понимаю, я могу в том же Джанго в views.py прописать в функции не вызов страницы, а вот эту команду

Да - можно через функцию вызвать команду. Только учтите, что если доступ к такой кнопке будет у нескольких пользователей, могут возникнуть проблемы из-за неоднократного вызова процесса. Если Вы планируете интерфейс для себя - то может подойти. Если нет - рассмотрите более сложный вариант с брокерами

Я понял, опробовал это. По части кнопки - в перспективе да, я планирую много пользователей, но они будут запускать разные файлы (я об этом позабочусь, у каждого будет свой экземпляр....). Но тут я так понимаю такой проблемы и нет. После запуска приложение больше ни от чего не зависит, пока его также авторизованный пользователь по СВОЕЙ кнопке на сайте не вырубит

Заработало, сейчас помещу отдельно объяснение, но ваш ответ мне и помог

Помогли на сайте, спасибо, mrgervant.
Пример рабочего кода в файле views фреймворка Django:
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse
import subprocess
import sys

def killbot(request):
     subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, 'static/prog/program.py'], shell = True)
     return TemplateResponse(request, "start.html")

При нажатии на кнопку на сайте запускается приложение (sys.executable - позволяет указать путь к интерпретатору языка, путь до программы указывается относительно файла views.py). В последней строке - страница сайта, загружаемая в ответ на ваш запрос, по нашей идее - это та же самая страница, с которой и прошло нажатие на кнопку (то есть пользователь ничего и не заметит, только надо внедрить переменную, которая будет показывает сайту, запущена ли программа, для показа разных кнопок - "ВРУБИТЬ" и "ВЫРУБИТЬ")

Кстати, если на вашем локальном компьютере sys.executable необязательный аргумент, то на сайте надо указывать обязательно
